# Message Sent to Deallocated instance when going to background

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management, uiviewcontroller, automatic-ref-counting

I am using ARC and testing on iOS7 (iPhone 5S).

I have a navigation controller (a) with a pushed UIViewController (b). b presents a modal NavigationViewController (c) via a manual segue. c then pushes a UIViewController (d).

So now we have 2 navigation stacks, one root and one modal.

I would like to dismiss the modal NavigationViewController (c) and all of its children whenever I go to background.

In UIViewController (b) I have the following code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(enteredBackground:)
                                             name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification object:nil];

}
-(void)enteredBackground:(NSNotification *)notification{
    if (self.presentedViewController) {
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
    }
}
- (void)dealloc {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}
```

This works fine if I am on C's rootViewController when I go to background, but crashes when I am on D.

`2013-10-20 22:49:49.008 MyApp[2596:60b] *** -[UIView release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x17036aa40`

How do I fix this? It seems like a view in the modal navigation stack is being sent `dealloc` and is already released. After looking in the debugger, the modal nvaigationcontroller (c) itself seems to still exist.

Comment: That must be a problem in some retain / release code in the view controller you are dismissing - please give more code around dismissed controller

Comment: There is no retain/release code. I am using arc. I am also not declaring and explicit weak or strong properties on any of these objects.

Comment: ARC doesn't mean no retain / releases :) you still have to define strong / weak references (which translates into retain or assign). If you don't undestand basics of retain/release I would suggest to use MRC and go to ARC after you know how to manually manage that - so you don't make basic mistakes.

Comment: I do understand. I am saying that I have no explicit retains/releases because of arc. But I am not holding any strong/weak references against any of the views, other than the references that storyboard makes.

Comment: @PRNDL Development Studios, Were you able to find the solution to this? I am xpriencing same at my side.

Comment: @PRNDL Development Studios, I think this would solve your problem. It solved mine. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18890716/new-uisearhbar-in-ios-7

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look! I hadn't found a solution yet.

Answer (score 0):

i have made an test sample and checked the same scenario , it is'nt crashing anywhere . Please check for any releases on object of type UIView in your ViewController C and D. Or can you post the code where you are doing all the stuff you mentioned above .

Comment: I can post, but there are no explicit releases or retains. I am using Arc. I will post code when I get back to my computer. Thanks.