# error shows "[UIView release]: message sent to deallocated instance" in IOS 7

Tags: objective-c, ios7, xcode4.6

I use Xcode 4.6 to develop application for IOS 5 to IOS 7.My application is working fine for all IOSs'. But when I run the application in IOS 7 real device, crashing the system (But not in every time). It's crashing when I logout the system and loging.

In My application,
- Use 3 storyboards
01. Storyboard for loggin
02. Storyboard for Mail module.
03. Storyboard for Packages.

In Mail module story board contains the UISplitView Controller. In master view contains the Logout button (cell). When I clicked it then load the Login storyboard's Login view.
I use following code for it.

```
        UIStoryboard *storyboard;

        if ([gaiDevice isEqual:@"IPAD"]) {
            if (gaAutoLayoutEnabled) {
                storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Login_iPad" bundle:nil];
            }
            else{
                storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Login_iPad_iOS5" bundle:nil];
            }

        }
        else{
            if (gaAutoLayoutEnabled) {
                 storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Login_iPhone" bundle:nil]; //Login_iPhone
            }
            else {
                 storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Login_iPhone_iOS5" bundle:nil]; //Login_iPhone
            }

        }

        LoginVC *myLogin = [[LoginVC alloc] init];
        gaSessionKey = @"1";
        gcURLPrefix = @"http://";
        myLogin =[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LoginView"];


        [self presentViewController:myLogin animated:NO completion:nil];
```

My problem is, When I go Mail module's some views and click logout. It goes to loggin view. from that when I go to Mail module screen , than application is crashed. This is happen only for IOS 7 device. Why is that ?

I cannot use NSZombie because it's come only IOS 7. IOS 7 simulator is not supported with XCode 4.6 instruments. So I cannot simulate it. Application is working fine for IOS 5,5.1,6.0 and 6.1 devices. only problem in IOS 7. Final error is "[UIView release]: message sent to deallocated instance" .I have been trying many ways since 2.5 days to sort out. :(
How can identify that UIView ??

Comment: Hey! I am experiencing the same problem, did you found the solution to yours?

Comment: Found solution for my problem :)
Maybe you might not need this, but still,
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18890716/new-uisearhbar-in-ios-7